# Webdriver - Locate Input via Label (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How do I locate an input field via its label using webdriver?

I like to test a certain web form which unfortunately uses dynamically generated
ids, so they're unsuitable as identifiers.

Yet, the labels associated with each web element strike me as suitable. 
Unfortunately I was not able to do it with the few suggestions
offered on the web. There is one thread here at SO, but which did not
yield an accepted answer:

[Selenium WebDriver Java - Clicking on element by label not working on certain labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704518/selenium-webdriver-java-clicking-on-element-by-label-not-working-on-certain-la)

To solve this problem in Java, it is commonly suggested to locate the label as an anchor via its text content and then specifying the xpath to the input element:

```
//label[contains(text(), 'TEXT_TO_FIND')]
```

I am not sure how to do this in python though.
My web element:

```
<div class="InputText">
    <label for="INPUT">
        <span>
            LABEL TEXT
        </span>
        <span id="idd" class="Required" title="required">
            *
        </span>
    </label>
    <span class="Text">
       <input id="INPUT" class="Text ColouredFocus" type="text" onchange="var wcall=wicketAjaxPost(';jsessionid= ... ;" maxlength="30" name="z1013400259" value=""></input>
   </span>
   <div class="RequiredLabel"> … </div>
   <span> … </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was not able to use CSS or XPATH expressions
on the site. IDs and names always changed.

The only solution to my problem I found was a dirty one - parsing
the source code of the page and extract the ids by string operations.
Certainly this is not the way webdriver was intended to be used, but
it works robustly.

Code:

```
lines = []
for line in driver.page_source.splitlines():
    lines.append(line)
    if 'LABEL TEXT 1' in line:
        id_l1 = lines[-2].split('"', 2)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a div and check that there is a `label` with an appropriate `span` inside, then get the `input` element from the `span` tag with class `Text`:

```
//div[@class='InputText' and contains(label/span, 'TEXT_TO_FIND')]/span[@class='Text']/input
```

Comment: Could you make this answer more explicit to me? Maybe orient on the example html I gave?

Comment: To use what @alecxe provided above, just change his "TEXT_TO_FIND" to "LABEL TEXT" (from your example). Which will find a div that has a label followed by a span with the text "LABEL TEXT", locating the 'home' point if you will. And then under that div find the span with the class Text which is followed by the input element that you want.